# How to build vdproj in x64 configuration in vs 2022

Tags: windows-installer, 64-bit, visual-studio-2022

How to Build Vdproj (MSI installer project ) in x64 using VS 2022 .

[image]

In configuration no option to select Platform . I using "**Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022**" Extension to build Vdproj  in VS 2022 .

Comment: After 10 years of adding: this stuff is basically deprecated, please use Wix instead, people still building vdprojs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting here as it may help others  .

We have to click "F4" to get property window of Setup project . Then in bottom of the options , we can see option to change "**Target Platform**" Option.

[image]